# C++, RapidJSON: object to JSON string

Tags: c++, c++11, rapidjson

Forgive me if this is simple, but I am rather new to C++ and can't make much sense of the documentation for RapidJSON.

I have an object that looks like this:

```
class DataPacket
{
public:
    DataPacket();
    ~DataPacket();

    string StopWatchId;
    long LengthOfTime;
    const uint8 * SomeBytes;
};
```

To construct my JSON I do the following:

```
Document document;
document.SetObject();
rapidjson::Document::AllocatorType& allocator = document.GetAllocator();

DataPacket datapacket = DataPacket();
datapacket.SomeBytes = data;
datapacket.StopWatchId = "SomeId";
datapacket.LengthOfTime = 30;

Value object(rapidjson::kObjectType);
object.AddMember("DataPacket", datapacket, allocator);
document.AddMember("root", object, allocator);

StringBuffer buffer;
Writer<StringBuffer> writer(buffer);

document.Accept(writer);
```

Then, to get the JSON string, I call `buffer.GetString()`.

This does not compile because it cannot convert from `DataPacket` to `rapidjson::Type`:

```
object.AddMember("DataPacket", datapacket, allocator);
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I convert my `dataPacket` to a JSON string with RapidJSON?

Comment: I don't have the environment to answer your question right now, but having used rapidjson and https://github.com/nlohmann/json, I'd seriously recommend giving nlohmann's json library a look. It's so much easier.

Comment: @AdamLamers. Had almost no problems using nlohmann/json either. Only those errors I introduced myself.

Comment: @AdamLamers This issue is not a bug or issue of RapidJSON. Using Nlohmann's cannot help you to create DOM by giving an arbitrary object. As C++ has no reflection (yet), serialization of object needs sending the members of object one by one.